# What's a nice way to say "fingers crossed"?

Tags: word-choice

What's a nice way to express any of the following -

- "Let's keep our fingers crossed"
- "I'll keep my fingers crossed!"
- (We / I) (are / am) keeping (our / my ) fingers crossed"

Comment: You probably better if you are looking for the figurative or literal meaning of it since the figurative meaning does not exist here.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, but I'd agree with oldergod, you might tend to say something like うまくいきますように！to show that you hope it goes well.

Comment: @b-wilson Possibly because "This question does not show any research effort" (part of the text shown when you move your mouse cursor over the down arrow).  Maybe this could be a starting point: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=fingers+crossed

Comment: -1 Because there's no explanation of what the idiom means in English, some people might not know what the idiom means.

Comment: @Ataraxia: This is a Japanese/English site for  not an English as a foreign language site. Stack exchange also has an EFL-type site where anybody not knowing the idiom can ask. (Actually if such readers can use this site then they are also probably quite able to google the expression.)

Comment: @Tim Personally, I think it's better when an explanation of the phrase is given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course not all cultures cross fingers when wishing for something. As far as I know crossed fingers don't signify anything in Japan.

The phrase "fingers crossed" would probably expressed using うまくいく "to go well", e.g.

> うまくいきますように
>   うまくいくといい(ね)

where the former is more formal and the second more conversational.

Comment: is correct - it has no meaning in Japan. It comes, by way of explanation, from making "the sign of the cross" - a Christian sign (yes, there are Christians in Japan, but no so many as to influence the culture)

Comment: @jmadsen Another theory is that it comes from pre-Christian superstition, but I don't think anyone knows for sure.

Answer (score 3):

As the other comments say, there is not really a literal translation but you can get a some mileage using the verb "to pray", 祈る。 The exact form will vary depending on context but following would work:

> Let's hope so. |そう祈ろう。
>
> Let's keep our fingers crossed. |みんなで幸運を祈りましょう。

My apple dictionary gives the following, which may help composing a longer sentence:

> keep ［have］ one's fingers crossed|
>
> （人さし指の上に中指を交差させて）願いがかなうことを祈る；
>
> （…になるよう）願う, 祈る｟that節｠.

Answer (score 2):

Not so strong in Japanese yet, but wouldn't simple 頑張って　（がんばって）　do, in this case?

Comment: "fingers crossed" suggests hoping for a streak of good luck. 頑張って is usually said to someone else as way of encouragement to do his/her best, which doesn't have anything to do with luck. But I agree that in a free translation "fingers crossed!" could be translated as "頑張ってね".